# Israeli esrogim after shemittah

Tags: halacha, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, shmita, disposal

Regarding *esrogim* the year after shemittah, when you prepare them to be made into jam, is it [*muttar*](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/591) to throw away the seeds?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for bringing your question here. Note that the site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer rabbinic advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends and use it to inform a consultation with your rabbi for a definitive ruling. On another note, might I recommend you [edit] the question to include *why* you think it may be necessary to use the seeds? That would make your question make a lot more sense to those unaware of your thought process and not intimately familiar with the concerns of _sh'mita_.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64181/what-to-do-with-a-shviit-etrog/64324#64324

Comment: Who says you can make them into jam?

Comment: @DannySchoemann, I think this is a dupe of my question from during Succos (which you linked).

Comment: Depending on the type of etrog you have i may want the seeds :D

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt it's not obvious to me that answers to your question would address what to do with the seeds, specifically (or even byproducts like seeds generally). I don't think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

It is permitted, as the prohibition of wasting shmitta produce only applies to the parts of the fruit normally eaten by people.
See in the following link shiur number 11 for detailed sources on the matter:
http://eretzhemdah.org/content.asp?PageId=823&lang=he