# Is making etrog jelly an acceptable use for an etrog?

Tags: food, mitzvah, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

I recall reading that when one is done with his lulav, he should save it and use it for another mitzvah (such burning chameitz) because once something has been used for a mitzvah it should be used for another (see [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8049/1362) answer). Some of the subtleties are mentioned [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/126719/feeding-animals-as-a-mitzvah). I'm still not sure if "any" mitzvah would count, but my current concern is limited to one practice.

But I also see that many people use their etrogim to make etrog jelly. Does that satisfy this same continuing of "honor" for the item used for a mitzvah? [This](https://halachayomit.co.il/en/default.aspx?HalachaID=5146) site discusses the eating as a segulah for pregnant women but does that rise to the level of mitzvah? Would it mean no one else can eat it because for others, it doesn't hold the same sacred position? Is simple "eating" a mitzvah that would count?

Comment: The bracha made on the jelly would be a Mitzvah?

Comment: I think I asked our shul's rabbi this as a kid and he said it was allowed. I don't remember the reasoning, but hey - whatever you eat, you'll be making a bracha on, so there's that.

Comment: @Chatzkel does that mean that all eating (because it all requires a mitzvah) is a mitzvah (which leads to other questions)...

Comment: @Harel13 I think of brachot before eating as hanehenin -- does this mean that all brachot on food are birchot hamitzvah?

Comment: That’s a good point. I do recall hearing a story about a chassid who asked his rebbe what is the difference between them? They both eat and sleep and learn etc. The rebbe answered that you make a bracha to be able to eat, while I eat to be able to make a bracha. So it depends on your outlook, but yes, it could be done as a mitzvah every time

Comment: Note there is a separate issue this year of kedushat shviit https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64455/759

Comment: Besides the issue raised by double aa there is the practical problem that esrogim grown for the mitzvah contain a lot of pesticides not meant for food. This means while the idea of it isn't necessarily a problem since it could be used during a seudas mitzvah eating food sprayed with industrial pesticides not meant for produce would be harming your health.

Comment: It's a nice thing to reuse something for a mitzvah, but it is  not an obligation. So one would definitely be allowed to use their esrog for food.